# how to dynamically set the row height and column width in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, typescript1.4, ag-grid

I have used   using this trying to fit the column and row width
how to dynamically set the row height and column width in ag-grid(please provide git hub code in typescript)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to set row height based on the content of a row.

### step 1 : set getRowHeight property to a javascript function.

gridOptions.getRowHeight = rowHeightFn

### step 2 : define rowHeightFn based on your requirement.

```
function rowHeightFn(params) {
   var result = 46;
   if (params.data.someKey === 2) {
      result = 2;
   }
   return result 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to set the row height based on the contents of the cells. To do this, set autoHeight=true on each column where height should be calculated from. For example, if one column is showing description text over multiple lines, then you may choose to select only that column to determine the line height.

https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-height/#auto-row-height

```
    {
      field: 'autoA',
      width: 300,
      wrapText: true,
      autoHeight: true,
      headerName: 'A) Auto Height',
    },
```

See the following code example: https://plnkr.co/edit/riWmCw1IgR7vBixB?open=main.ts