# How to calculate multiline cell's height in Ag-Grid based on width and text length?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

There is an Ag-Grid table component. It has a column with text in each cell. Text is longer than cell's width. Cell should be multiline and it's height should fit text on changing of width.
I found how to make cell multiline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246606/ag-grid-multiline-cell-content)
I found how to update cell height on width change [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891835/how-to-dynamically-set-the-row-height-and-column-width-in-ag-grid)

So I think that method getRowHeight() which is called on each manual moving of the column's border, - could help. The question is - how to calculate it's height so that it fit the size of the multiline text in the cell? It seems that there should be a function where height of the cell depends of the length of the text string in the cell and current width?
Or maybe is there a better way to dynamically change height of a multiline cell with text (and row) on it's changed width?)

Answer (score 0):

As of a few versions ago, ag-grid supports out of the box auto row-height

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/#auto-row-height

Have a look here, all you need to do is enable it.

Comment: I see, there's an autoHeight:true property, which makes ag-grid to fit to columns, but it has a big flaw: it doesnt use all space of the line.

Comment: It creates second line long before the end of the first line - and cell which could easily show text using only one line, somehow takes two lines. I didn't find how to change settings of autoresizing and that's why I am trying to do this manually with method getRowHeight()